# Building a Sine wave(Sinudoid) javascript

Tags: javascript, math, charts

I'm trying to build a sine wave with a jscharts (http://www.jscharts.com/) lib, but the graph code below doesn't want to draw one 
    **First attempt//failed**

```
var myData = new Array(1024);  
var a = 0;  
var g;  
for (var j = 0; j < 1024; j++) {  
    g = Math.sin(0.00628 * j);  
    myData.push([a, g]);  
    a++;  
}
```

**Second Attempt//failed**

```
myData = new Array(1024);  
var a = 0;  
var g;  
for (var j = 0; j < 1024; j++) {          
    myData.push([j, Math.sin(0.00628 * j)]);  
}
```

When i type something like

```
myData = new Array([1996, 22], [1997, 36], [1998, 37], [1999, 45], [2000, 50], [2001, 55], [2002, 61], [2003, 61], [2004, 62], [2005, 66], [2006, 73]);
```

the drawing goes well

can you guide me how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using

```
var myData = new Array(1024);
```

you are initializing an array with 1024 `undefined` values. If you then use `push`, you will add *even more* elements, leaving the first 1024 `undefined`. For example:

```
var myData = new Array(3);
myData.push('Hello'); // myData is now [undefined, undefined, undefined, 'Hello']
```

Try this

```
var myData = [];
for(var j = 0; j < 1024; j++) {
    myData.push([j, Math.sin(0.00628 * j)]);
}
```

A more basic sine wave could be produced like this:

```
var myData = [];
for(var j = 0; j < 2 * Math.PI; j += 0.1) {
    myData.push([j, Math.sin(j)]);
}
```

You can see this one in action here: <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rr8r4/)</kbd>

Comment: @Teemu I would usually mention that myself – but then someone starts a discussion on why it isn't *that* bad to use it. But I agree, I would also suggest only ever using `[]`.

Comment: @IngoBürk I used this 
var myData = [];
            var step = 15;
            for (var j = 0; j < 40; j++) {

                myData.push([j, Math.sin(j * (2 * Math.PI) / step)]);
            }
instead, and it worked fine, the problem is that this lib just can't process an array with 1024 values, on my machine it starts to have problems even with 40 values

Comment: @YuriyKravets Yes, it seems to be rather slow. You might have more luck with another library. Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it helped you (with the `undefined` thing, for example). Also, if you have any more questions, feel free to ask them.

Comment: @IngoBürk yes it was really helpful and I really appreciate your answer but I don't 15 reputation needed to upvote an answer :( sorry 'bout that